# ServerSocket listening in onCreate causes "Timeout creating service" exception

Tags: android, sockets

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service{
ServerSocket server = null;
Socket socketClient = null;

private static final String TAG = BackgroundService.class.getSimpleName();
Thread socketThread;
int temp =0;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    if (BackgroundService.class.getName().equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Bound by intent " + intent);
        return apiEndpoint;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

private final Object latestIncomingMessage = new Object();
private List<MessageCollectorListener> listeners = new ArrayList<MessageCollectorListener>();
private Message message = new Message(" ");

private MessageCollectorApi.Stub apiEndpoint = new MessageCollectorApi.Stub() {
    @Override
    public void removeListener(MessageCollectorListener listener) throws RemoteException {
        synchronized (listener) {
            listeners.remove(listener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Message getValue() throws RemoteException {
        synchronized (latestIncomingMessage) {
            return message;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addListener(MessageCollectorListener listener) throws RemoteException {
        synchronized (listener) {
            listeners.add(listener);
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    socketThread = new Thread() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(8080);
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            };

            while(true){
                try {
                    socketClient = server.accept();
                    InputStream is = socketClient.getInputStream();
                    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(socketClient.getOutputStream());
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                    char[] buff = new char[10];
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                    br.read(buff);
                    synchronized (latestIncomingMessage) {
                        message.setValue(String.valueOf(buff));
                    }
                    synchronized (listeners) {
                        for (MessageCollectorListener listener : listeners) {
                            try {
                                listener.handleUpdatedMessages();
                            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to notify listener " + listener, e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                   buff = new char[10];
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    socketThread.start();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    socketThread.destroy();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the server is listening in the main thread, the method `onCreate` is not finished until the server gets some connection with a client, and you get timeout on `onCreate`. To avoid this, run the server in another thread.

To read a buffer, not by `readline`, you can do the following:

```
char buff = new char[MAX_PACKET_SIZE];
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
br.read(buff);
```

Comment: by the way... do you know any other way to do bufferreading other than read line ? since it expects for a line terminator..

Comment: thank you... one more doubt...in the above code.. the process request happens only when it receives a socket connection... Can the socket remain open and read the messages whenever it comes in ??? Or is this thinking wrong ?

Comment: I *think* that once a connection has been accepted, it is bound to the same IP / port. use loop that after the close connection opens a new one, I think this is a better approach. There are many examples for this. Here is one of them: http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/

Comment: hey...this is the same thing that i am doing in the above code...listenSocket does the same in the while() loop

Comment: This is fine. but as the original answer, it should be done in a separate thread.

Comment: hi...i have edited the code as per your suggestions..but still the second time i am not able to recieve the socket message from the client...

Comment: have posted the question in ur mail but not the code as i am restricted from doing so...code i have edited here...

Comment: @MyByD: when the socket gets disconnected from the client.. this starts runnning in an infinite loop... any solution to this ?

Comment: @MyByD: server.accept() is kept outside the loop...so continous transmission works...but once the socket gets disconnected...it goes for a toss..inifinite loop...